# Is there a way to update the children before the framer motion disassembles the items?

Tags: framer-motion

I would like to update the content and the border before the element dismounts.

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-cerf-siq8e?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use AnimatePresence here?

Comment: because I want to animate and remove the element from screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never allowing the content to change as you are testing for true only:

```
 {isOpen && (
```

The value will never be false within the component.

You can simplify the example by removing `AnimatedPresense` and introducing [useCycle](https://www.framer.com/api/motion/utilities/#usecycle) to cycle efficiently between animation variants.

```
import { motion, useCycle } from "framer-motion";
import * as React from "react";

const variants = {
  open: { 
    height: "auto" ,
    transition: { duration: 0.8, ease: "easeInOut" }
  },
  collapsed: { 
    height: 0 ,
    transition: { duration: 0.8, ease: "easeInOut" }
  }
}

export default function App() {
  const [variant, toggleVariant] = useCycle('open', 'collapsed');

  return (
    <div className="App">
        <motion.section
          style={{ overflow: "hidden" }}
          variants={variants}
          animate={variant}
        >
          <div
            style={{
              border: `5px solid ${variant === 'open' ? "red" : "blue"}`,
              height: 100
            }}
          >
            {variant}
          </div>
        </motion.section>
      <button onClick={toggleVariant}>
        {variant === 'open' ? 'collapse me': 'expand me'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-satoshi-xli62)

Comment: No problem. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem and can help others.